# Handling consecutive delimiters with strsep() in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read a string word by word in C using strsep() function, which can be also done using strtok(). When there are consecutive delimiters -in my case the empty space- the function does not ignore them. I am expected to use strsep() and couldn't figure out the solution. I'd appreciate it if one of you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char newLine[256]= "scalar             i";

  char *q;
  char *token;
  q = strdup(newLine);

  const char delim[] = " ";
    
  token = strsep(&q, delim);
  printf("The token is: \"%s\"\n", token);
    
  token = strsep(&q, delim);    
  printf("The token is: \"%s\"\n", token);

  return 0;
}
```

Actual output is:

```
The token is: "scalar"
The token is: ""
```

What I expected is:

```
The token is: "scalar"
The token is: "i"
```

To do that I also tried to write a while loop so that I could continue until the token is non-empty.
But I cannot equate tokens with "", " ", NULL or "\n". Somehow the token is not equal to any of these.

Comment: The second token was the empty string between two `' ' ` delimiter characters. The result you expected is the behaviour of `strtok`.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I know I can do that with strtok(). As I stated in the question, I am SUPPOSED to use strsep().

Comment: "The token is not equal to any of the delimiters". No it never will be, that's is what the function does.

Comment: From [the GNU manual page for `strsep()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html): "The strsep() function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(3), since the latter cannot handle empty fields."  If you *don't want* adjacent delimiter characters to be treated as delimiting empty fields, then using `strsep()` is counterproductive.  If you are required to use `strsep()` anyway, yet want to merge adjacent delimiters into one, then you'll need to programmatically ignore any empty tokens that `strsep()` reports.

Comment: I agree, trying to force a non-standard function to do what the standard function does doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `strsep()`, while convenient is not in the standard C library, and will only be available on Unix systems with BSD-4.4 C library support. That's most Unix'ish systems today, but still.

Anyway, `strsep()` supports empty fields. That means that if your string has consecutive delimiters, it will find empty, length-0, tokens between each of these delimiters. For example, the tokens for string `"ab  cd"` will be:

1. `"ab"`
2. `""`
3. `"cd"`

2 delimiters -> 3 tokens.

Now, you also said:

> I cannot equate tokens with "", " ", NULL or "\n". Somehow the token is not equal to any of these.

I am guessing what you were trying to perform is simply comparison, e.g. `if (my_token == "") { ... }`. That won't work, because that is a comparison of *pointers*, not of the strings' contents. Two strings may have identical characters at different places in memory, and that is particularly likely with the example I just gave, since `my_token` will be dynamic, and will *not* be pointing to the static-storage-duration string `""` used in the comparison.

Instead, you will need to use `strcmp(my_token,"")`, or better yet, just check manually for the first char being `'\0'`.